# localStorage is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Single Page Application with pure JavaScript (no additional frameworks or libraries). The problem is that the values I add to the TODO list are not storing in the localStorage (and are not showing).

I would appreciate any help with that task.

**How can I simplify the code? (without using any additional libraries and frameworks (ex.jquery etc.))**

Here is my code:

```js
let inputTask = document.getElementById('toDoEl');
let editTask = document.getElementById('editTask');
let checkTask = document.getElementById('list');
let emptyList = document.getElementById('emptyList');

let items = [];
let id = [];
let labelToEdit = null;
const empty = 0;

let pages = ['index', 'add', 'modify'];

load();

function load() {
  items = loadFromLocalStorage();
  id = getNextId();

  items.forEach(item => renderItem(item));
}

function show(shown) {
  location.href = '#' + shown;
  pages.forEach(function(page) {
    document.getElementById(page).style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}

function getNextId() {

  for (let i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    let item = items[i];
    if (item.id > id) {
      id = item.id;
    }
  }
  id++;
  return id;
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  let localStorageItems = localStorage.getItem('items');

  if (localStorageItems === null) {
    return [];
  }

  return JSON.parse(localStorageItems);
}

function saveToLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
}

function setChecked(checkbox, isDone) {
  if (isDone) {
    checkbox.classList.add('checked');
    checkbox.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/b1WeN9/done_s.png';
    
    let newPosition = checkTask.childElementCount - 1;
    let listItem = checkbox.parentNode;
    listItem.classList.add('checked');
    checkTask.removeChild(listItem);
    checkTask.appendChild(listItem);
  } else {
    checkbox.classList.remove('checked');
    checkbox.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/nqRqUp/todo_s.png';
    let listItem = checkbox.parentNode;
    listItem.classList.remove('checked');
  }
}

function renderItem(item) {
  let listItem = document.getElementById('item_template').cloneNode(true);
  listItem.style.display = 'block';
  listItem.setAttribute('data-id', item.id);

  let label = listItem.querySelector('label');
  label.innerText = item.description;

  let checkbox = listItem.querySelector('input');

  checkTask.appendChild(listItem);

  setChecked(checkbox, item.isDone);

  emptyList.style.display = 'none';

  return listItem;
}

function createNewElement(task, isDone) {

  let item = { isDone, id: id++, description: task };
  items.push(item);

  saveToLocalStorage();

  renderItem(item);
}

function addTask() {  
  if (inputTask.value) {
    createNewElement(inputTask.value, false);
    
    inputTask.value = '';

    show('index');
  }
}

function modifyTask() {  
  if (editTask.value) {

    let item = findItem(labelToEdit);
    item.description = editTask.value;
    labelToEdit.innerText = editTask.value;
    saveToLocalStorage();
   
    show('index');
  }
}

function findItem(child) {
  let listItem = child.parentNode;

  let id = listItem.getAttribute('data-id');
  id = parseInt(id);
  let item = items.find(item => item.id === id);

  return item;
}

// Chanhe img to checked
function modifyItem(label) {

  labelToEdit = label;
  editTask.value = label.innerText;

  show('modify');

  editTask.focus();
  editTask.select();
}

function checkItem(checkbox) {
  let item = findItem(checkbox);

  if (item === null) {
    return;
  }
  item.isDone = !item.isDone;

  saveToLocalStorage();

  setChecked(checkbox, item.isDone);
}

function deleteItem(input) {
  let listItem = input.parentNode;

  let id = listItem.getAttribute('data-id');
  id= parseInt(id);
  for (let i in items) {
    if (items[i].id === id) {
      items.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (items.length === empty) {
    emptyList.style.display = 'block';
  }

  saveToLocalStorage();

  listItem.parentNode.removeChild(listItem);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h2, li, #notification {
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#root {
  width: 400px; 
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#root>ul {
  display: block;
}
#addButton {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.checkbox, .delete { 
  height: 24px;
  bottom: 0; 
}
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}
.delete {
  float: right;
}
ul {
  margin: 20px 30px 0 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toDoEl {
  width: 50%;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
label {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: auto;
}
li.checked { 
  background-color: gray;
}
span.button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#add, #modify {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Homework 12 - Simple TODO List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <!--Main page-->
    <div id="index">
      <h2>Simple TODO Application</h2> 
      <button class="button" id="addButton" onclick="show('add')">Add New Task</button>
      <p id="emptyList">TODO is empty</p>
      <ul id="list">
        <li id="item_template" style="display: none">
          <input class="checkbox" type="image" alt="checkbox" src="https://image.ibb.co/nqRqUp/todo_s.png" onclick="checkItem(this)">
          <label onclick="modifyItem(this)"></label>
          <input id="delete" class="delete" type="image" alt="remove" src="https://image.ibb.co/dpmqUp/remove_s.jpg" onclick="deleteItem(this)">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Add page-->
    <div id="add">
      <h2>Add Task</h2>
      <input type="text" id="toDoEl">
      <button class="button cancel" onclick="show('index')">Cancel</button>
      <button class="button save" onclick="addTask()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    <!--Modify page-->
    <div id="modify">
      <h2>Modify item</h2>
      <input type="text" id="editTask">
      <button class="button cancel" onclick="show('index')">Cancel</button>
      <button class="button save" onclick="modifyTask()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./src/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific and tell which function is not working

Comment: what are the results of your debugging work? How far do the items get? do you have `items` in `saveToLocalStorage()`?

Comment: Jeff , yes, I’m adding elements in getNextId() function

Comment: consider [Chromium help](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does appear to work. If you `console.log(JSON.parse(localStorageItems))` right above line 49 in the `loadFromLocalStorage` function, it shows as expected in the console. Also, upon refreshing the items persist.

If what you mean is that you're checking localStorage and you don't *see* the items, it might be that you're looking at the preview version of localStorage. (I'm assuming you're using Chrome.) Hover over the top of the empty section and pull down, this should reveal the values stored. If you click on one, it should show in the preview section. I think this was a Chrome dev tools UI change recently implemented.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code in Codepen and it works.

[image]